# say we have a -= dict[c] > 0. what does the > mean after the -=?

Tags: python

```
import collections
import character_counter

def min_window(str1, str2):
result_char, missing_char = collections.Counter(str2), len(str2)

    import collections
    import character_counter
    
    def min_window(str1, str2):
        result_char, missing_char = collections.Counter(str2), len(str2)
        
        i = p = q = 0
        for j, c in enumerate(str1, 1):
            
            missing_char -= result_char[c] > 0
            result_char[c] -= 1
            if not missing_char:
                while i < q and result_char[str1[i]] < 0:
                    result_char[str1[i]] += 1
                    i += 1
                if not q or j - i <= q - p:
                    p, q = i, j
    
        return str1[p:q]
               
    str1 = "PRWSOERIUSFK"
    str2 = "OSU"
    print("Original Strings:\n",str1,"\n",str2)
    print("Minimum window:")
    
    print(min_window(str1,str2))
```

I am trying to understand this piece of code. Twice there is `<` or `>` after an addition or subtraction. What does the `>` mean when you put it after an operator and a value?

I tried to experiment:

```
val = 5
val2= 8

val += val2 > -1

print(val)
# this outputs 6, not 13 as i was expecting.
# when val2 < -1, it outputs 5
# why does this add only one?
```

Comment: It means greater than. `result_char[c] > 0` -> either True (`1`) or False (`0`).

Comment: It's `val += (val2 > -1)`, not `(val += val2) > -1`, which isn't even a valid expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to your experimental code, `val2 > -1` is an expression that has a value of either `True` or `False`.

But the boolean values are really integers in disguise, with `True` being equivalent to 1 and `False` being equivalent to 0.

So if `val2 > -1` evaluates as `True`, you are adding 1 to `val`, and if it evaluates as `False` you are adding 0 to `val`.